# How to search files in google drive using apps script based on custom keyword with regex?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have script to search file in google drive with apps script based on keyword.

e.g. I want to search file that contains "FX.ABCDEF".

I using **fullText contains {text}**.

Here the code :

```
var searchFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles('fullText contains "FX.ABCDEF" ')
```

On the other hand many keywords are similar to **FX.ABCDEF**. Characters after **FX.** is dynamic. Therefore I don't want to define keywords like that over and over again. So in cases like this a simplification is needed using **regex**.
So we can write :

```
/FX\.[A-Z]+/g
```

I'm still confused about implementing **regex** in **searchFiles**.

Comment: The [`params` docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms) do not mention any regex, so it is most likely impossible to use with `searchFiles`.

Comment: Ok thank for your explanation bro. But, how to got the best solution for my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching in Drive files contents using regex is not currently supported. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms) is the list of the available search syntax for Drive file contents.

If this feature is really important for your application consider filing a Feature Request [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features).

Answer (score 0):

Get all files, put their names in array and do RegEx search inside this array:

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var file_names = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) file_names.push(files.next().getName());

  var reg = /.FX\.[A-Z]+/g;
  var found_names = file_names.filter(n => reg.test(n));
  Logger.log(found_names);
}
```

This way you will get the array with wanted names. You can take names from this array and get the file by the name. But keep in mind -- there can be many different files with the same name. You have to handle this collision some way.

Comment: I use the keyword "fullText contains {keyword}" because it can read files that have a specified word either filename or words in the file.  Meanwhile, your script only reads the filename.

Comment: what I mean is the use of regex in the "searchFiles (regex)" section.  If it impossible, is there another solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get where exactly your problem was. I have no solution for this. I would be glad to know the answer someday.